# Type for object that has one and only one property from a list of valid property names

Tags: typescript

How can we model this without creating a union type that has each possible object?

```
type ValidRootPropertyNames =
  'Property1' |
  'Property2';

type ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList =
  { Property1: string; } |
  { Property2: string; };

const obj1: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // okay
  Property1: 'foo',
};

const obj2: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // okay
  Property2: 'foo',
};

const obj3: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // error
  Property3: 'foo',
};
```

The above does what we need; the problem is that it becomes cumbersome when there are dozens of valid property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [distributive behavior of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to create the union automatically from the union of keys:

```
type ValidRootPropertyNames =
'Property1' |
'Property2';

type ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList =
    ValidRootPropertyNames extends infer T ? // Introduce a type parameter to have distributive behavior 
    T extends string ? Record<T, string> : never : never;

const obj1: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // okay
    Property1: 'foo',
};

const obj2: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // okay
    Property2: 'foo',
};

const obj3: ObjectWithRootPropertyNameFromList = { // error
    Property3: 'foo',
};
```

Comment: @ShaunLuttin it's just there to introduce a type parameter, conditional types distribute over naked type parameters so we need to introduce a type parameter that is `ValidRootPropertyNames`

Comment: What does the word "distribute" mean in this context?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin this should explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter/51651684#51651684

Comment: Let me see whether I understand or not. "Distribute" here means "replace" or "substitute." So, for instance, if we are distributing X over a union type, then we are replacing each of the union members with X. Is that right?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Sort of ... distributing over a union means that the conditional type is applied to each member of the union. So in this case `Record<T, string>` is applied for each memeber of `ValidRootPropertyNames ` so we get `Record<'Property1', string> | Record<'Property1', string>`

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. My vocabulary wasn't quite right. The mot juste is "applied."