# TypeScript union with exclude and type guard

Tags: typescript

Why is the following code has an error?

I'm wondering it's a bug of TypeScript compiler.

```js
type A =
  | {
      type: 'a';
      a: string;
    }
  | {
      type: 'b';
      b: string;
    };

type X = {
  x: string;
} & A;

type XX = Pick<X, Exclude<keyof X, 'x'>> & {
  x: number;
};

const x: XX = {} as any;

if (x.type === 'a') {
  // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'XX'
  console.log(x.a);
}
```

[You can try this code on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20A%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'a'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'b'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20X%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20A%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20XX%20%3D%20Pick%3CX%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20X%2C%20'x'%3E%3E%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20XX%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(x.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20'a')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Property%20'a'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'XX'.ts(2339)%0D%0A%20%20console.log(x.a)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is just a consequence of how union types work. Union (unless narrowed) only allow access to common properties. So when you say `keyof X` the only properties that will be present in the resulting string literal union are `x` (which is no dependent on the union) and `type` which is common to both union members.  `Pick` also uses `keyof` behind the scenes and so has the same issue, it will be able to pick any members of the union that are common to all union members.

You can get the desired behavior, but you can't use `keyof` and `Pick` directly. You need to use the in a conditional type with a naked type parameter. Conditional types will distribute over members of a union (you can read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) about this behavior or a more concise version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter/51651684#51651684)) allowing us to apply `keyof` and `Pick` over each member of the union instead of the union as a whole.

```
type A =
  | {
      type: 'a';
      a: string;
    }
  | {
      type: 'b';
      b: string;
    };

type X = {
  x: string;
} & A;


type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type UnionPick<T, K extends UnionKeys<T>> = T extends any ? Pick<T, Extract<K, keyof T>> : never 
type XX = UnionPick<X, Exclude<UnionKeys<X>, 'x'>> & {
  x: number;
};

const x: XX = {} as any;

if (x.type === 'a') {
  console.log(x.a);
}
```