# Set type based on sibling value's type

Tags: typescript

I have code like this :

```
interface Entity{
    value : number | string;
}
interface Abc{
    entity: Entity;
    entityValues : number[] | string[] // <----- I want to change this type
}
```

Even when I have an entity object of type number, entity values can be `string[]` or `number[]`. Since already have entity set, I want entityValues also to be dynamically determined.

Comment: So you want `type Abc = {entity: {value: number}; entityValues: number[]} | {entity: {value: string}; entityValues: string[]}`?

Comment: And if not, please flesh out your question to explain your use case.

Comment: That should work , let me give it a try . If I have more types for entity, it gets too verbose. I thought there would be a simpler option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is a way to make the `entityValues` field a :

```
// Distribute the types of a union across arrays
// This gets us `string[] | number[]` instead of `(string | number)[]`
// If you want to store the values of _all_ the fields, instead of fields of a single type
// simply use `Entity[EntityFields][]` for `entityValues`
// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996824/135978 for more information
type HomogenousArray<T> = T extends unknown ? T[] : never;

interface Abc<Entity, EntityFields extends keyof Entity = keyof Entity> {
  entity: Entity,
  // Values of a particularly typed sub-section of your entity's fields
  entityValues: HomogenousArray<Entity[EntityFields]>
  // Values of any or all of your entity's fields
  anyEntityValues: Entity[EntityFields][]
}
```

Usage is very straightforward:

```
interface Entity {
  id: number,
  value: string
}

type Z = Abc<Entity>;

const z: Z = {
  entity: {id: 1, value: "hi"},
  entityValues: [1, 2, 3],
                // ["strings", ""] will also work
                // ["strings", 123] will *not* work
  anyEntityValues: [1, "mixed types", 2, "work here"] 

};
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996824/135978