# Typescript collapsing union type with undefined

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, typescript-generics, tsconfig, conditional-types

I am trying to implement a variadiac argument for a generic function such that when the generic type is undefined, no argument is required, otherwise a single argument is matching the specified type.

For example

```
const a = variadiacFunc(); // ok
const b = variadicFunc<string>('A string') // ok
const c = variadicFunc<string>() // error Expected 1 arguments, but got 0; Arguments for the rest parameter 'context' were not provided.
const d = variadicFunc<string | undefined>() // ok
const e = variadicFunc<string | undefined>('Another string') // ok
```

I am implementing this using conditional tuple types

```
type ConditionalTupleArg<T> = [T] extends [undefined] ? [] : [T];
const variadicFunc = <T = undefined>(...context: ConditionalTupleArg<T>) {...};
```

Inspecting the types in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYYEsIDsCGANgIJQDmAKgK5iHAA8FAfHALxwDaFAunKDMFwATAM6cqw4ADMsuYEN4B+TrwBcnHgChNSFHACqkmXKFpchRG3SYcBEuWq0GEodNnymAbjgB6Hyp1kVABlGChZMjQoQ1djeSsMbDwiUkoaOnoRMIi4AB84FzcTL19-Dizw3DI8gqN3BUC9UMrI80t2RNsUh3SGCoiSv05+qu5NIA), this seems to do exactly what I want

```
export type OptionalArgTuple<T> = [T] extends [undefined] ? [] : [T]

type UndefinedOnly = OptionalArgTuple<undefined>; // []
type StringOrUndefined = OptionalArgTuple<string | undefined>; // [string | undefined]
type StringOnly = OptionalArgTuple<string>; // [string]
```

In my local create-react-app project I am seeing an error because StringOrUndefined is resolving to `[string]` rather than `[string | undefined]`  which is causing compile errors for invocation involving union with `undefined` in the case of `d` above.

I'm not sure why this is happening, if there are tsconfig options which control or influence this behavior which may be configured incorrectly in my local project.

The project is currently configured to use typescript 4.7.4, and my tsconfig.json is

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE: explicitly running `tsc --v` locally suggests that the code is building with 4.5.4 and *not* 4.7.4 as is listed in my package.json, however, using v4.5.4 in TS playground the inferred types are still what I am expecting.

UPDATE 2: I set `typescript.tsdk` in my vscode settings.json to point to the correct typescript version and the error displayed in the editor has now changed

```
variadicFunc<string | undefined>(); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0; Arguments for the rest parameter 'ctx' were not provided.
```

Allowing the types to be distributed resolves the error:

```
export type ConditionalTupleArg<T> = T extends undefined ? [] : [T];

variadicFunc<string | undefined>(); // ok
variadicFunc<string | undefined>('a string'); // ok
```

So I think the issue my local build using an old (4.5.4) version of typescript.

Comment: Enable `strictNullChecks` (or even better, `strict`)

Comment: @caTS I applied those, as well as all other options specified in the tsconfig of TS playground and same error.

Comment: For some reason my colleagues using MacOS the code I'm having issues with compiles just fine so I think something was b0rked in my local environment.  Setting `strict` in my tsconfig and fixing the version of typescript being used resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So this small adjustment is fixing your problem.

```
export type OptionalArgTuple<T> = T extends undefined ? [] : [T]

type UndefinedOnly = OptionalArgTuple<undefined>; // []
type StringOrUndefined = OptionalArgTuple<string | undefined>; // [string | undefined]
type StringOnly = OptionalArgTuple<string>; // [string]

const variadicFunc = <T = undefined>(...context: OptionalArgTuple<T>)=>{throw new Error("not implemented")};
const a = variadicFunc<undefined>()
const b = variadicFunc<undefined|string>() //ok
const c = variadicFunc<string>("a")
```

So error is caused by the type
`export type OptionalArgTuple<T> = T extends [undefined] ? [] : [T]`. By using `[undefined]` typescript won't distribute your union type. That means typescript will create ONE function
with this signature

`function variadicFunc<undefined|string>("as") \\ type variadicFunc = (...args:[undefined|string])=> unknown`

and this function will always required at least one argument.

What you actually want to achieve is this:

`variadicFunc<undefined|string>("as") \\ type variadicFunc = (...args:[])=> unknown | (...args:[string] )=> unknown`

And you will achieve this by removing the brackets around undefined and distribute your union type.
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=11&ssc=36&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5CcCWUB2AhgDYCCMA5gCoCuExIAPFQHwIC8CVC4cI+AEwDOCGoJAAzHPhACEAfgQBtALoIAXMqorgwFGgQBVcVJkCM+Ysg6ZseImUq16TMQMnTZLANwIA9H7KOvroAMpwMNIUGDDG7qayNli4BCTk1HQMjEIRUQgAPqImngI+-oFKOZH4FAVF8SXBqGG5NRZWSXapjhku2a0UZQHKVVE6wADGBDkIAG6EkYQCOBMAYmITNsw2bh5mLAAUAHQnU-h8YHCayfZpTplMrACU7CwA3nAAFjBQAO4IMn+AFEYD8YAcAET4KCIHAAWxccP4fAEEKeAF9vJNpohCDZ5otlmsNoxdglSgcntj8DMAEb4hY4JYrdb4Cak4pmfKjGqHCGEIRo6kzTacAlMoms9k8waQwhooA)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996797/typescript-conditional-type-array-of-union-type-distribution) is a link to an stackoverflow post that will provide more information on this topic

Comment: That's I'd already found this and made the change independently, however the underlying issue was that the `| undefined` is being stripped out of the type leaving only  `[string]` in either case.