# How to recursively Omit key from type

Tags: typescript, recursion, types

I want to write a type utility that omits fields recursively.
Something that you would name and use like that `OmitRecursively<SomeType, 'keyToOmit'>`

I've tried to do it using mapped types + conditional typing but I stuck on the case when all required fields got typed correctly (hence field disappeared from nested type), but optional fields are ignored with that approach.

```
// This is for one function that removes recursively __typename field 
// that Appolo client adds
type Deapolify<T extends { __typename: string }> = Omit<
  { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { __typename: string } ? Deapolify<T[P]> : T[P] },
  '__typename'
>

// Or more generic attempt

type OmitRecursively<T extends any, K extends keyof T> = Omit<
  { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any ? Omit<T[P], K> : never },
  K
>
```

Expected behavior would be root and all nested keys that have a type with a key that should be recursively omitted is omitted.
E.g

```js
type A = {
  keyToKeep: string
  keyToOmit: string
  nested: {
    keyToKeep: string
    keyToOmit: string
  }
  nestedOptional?: {
    keyToKeep: string
    keyToOmit: string
  }
}

type Result = OmitRecursively<A, 'keyToOmit'>

type Expected = {
  keyToKeep: string
  nested: {
    keyToKeep: string
  }
  nestedOptional?: {
    keyToKeep: string
  }
} 

Expected === Result
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't call `OmitRecursevly` recursively, and I also would only apply the omit recursively if the property type is an object, otherwise it should mostly work:

```
type OmitDistributive<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends any ? (T extends object ? Id<OmitRecursively<T, K>> : T) : never;
type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T] : T[P]} // Cosmetic use only makes the tooltips expad the type can be removed 
type OmitRecursively<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Omit<
    { [P in keyof T]: OmitDistributive<T[P], K> },
    K
>

type A = {
    keyToKeep: string
    keyToOmit: string
    nested: {
        keyToKeep: string
        keyToOmit: string
    }
    nestedOptional?: {
        keyToKeep: string
        keyToOmit: string
    }
}

type Result = OmitRecursively<A, 'keyToOmit'>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=22&pln=10&pc=22#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)

**Edit**: Updated to reflect addition of built-in `Omit` helper type. For older versions just define Omit.

**Note** `Id` is used mostly for cosmetic reasons (it forces the compiler to expand `Pick` in tooltips) and can be removed, it sometimes can cause problems in some corener cases.

**Edit**
The original code did not work with `strictNullChecks` because the type of the property was `type | undefined`. I edited the code to distribute over unions. The conditional type `OmitDistributive` is used for its distributive behavior (we use it for this reason not the condition). This means that `OmitRecursively` will be applied to each member of the union.

**Explanations**

By default the `Omit` type does not work well on unions. `Omit` looks at a union as a whole and will not extract properties from each member of the union. This is mostly due to the fact that `keyof` will only return common properties of a union (so `keyof undefined | { a: number }` will actually be `never`, since there are no common properties).

Fortunately there is a way to drill into a union using conditional type. Conditional types will distribute over naked type parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter/51651684#51651684) for my explanation or the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). In the case of `OmitDistributive` we don't really care about the condition (that is why we use `T extends any`) we just care that if we use conditional types `T` will in turn be each member in the union.

This means that these types are equivalent:

```
OmitDistributive<{ a: number, b: number} | undefined}, 'a'> = 
     OmitRecursively<{ a: number, b: number}, 'a'> | undefined
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
I just checked that code a second ago. Can it be connected with compiler config somehow?

Comment: @AndriiLos Works yeas, strict null checsk causes issues will fix in a second

Comment: @AndriiLos fixed to work with strict null checks, as a side effect it will also drill into unions and remove the properties from each union member (this is probably a good thing IMO)

Comment: amazing. It works! Question is. Can u maybe explain it in detail, step by step? Because I'm totally lost on OmitDistributive and others :)
Also, why did you use different Omit and not the original one that TS has baked in?

Comment: @AndriiLos Omit is not part of the standard library you probably have a library installed, I try to provide fully working code where possible :). I will try to add a couple of links to explain the distributive behavior of conditional types. If you have questions  more question you can reach me on gitter :)

Comment: @AndriiLos edited the answer, hope it's a bit more clear

Comment: Works like a charm with Typescript 3.8.x. You are a wizard. Thank you!!

Comment: How to get rid of this type error on line 7 in the playground link?
Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.

Comment: @Rocaboca `Omit` was added to the base lib since this answer. Fixed (link works now). Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Constraining generic type T to any does nothing and is unnecessary

Comment: How does this work ith Arrays? The __typename can also be nested in arrays. Also how would the utility function be typed to work with this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extended post about this topic: [Writing a Recursive Utility Type in TypeScript](https://www.bbss.dev/posts/typescript-recursive-omit/).

First, the code:

```
type UnionOmit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = T extends unknown
  ? Omit<T, K>
  : never;
type NullUnionOmit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = null extends T
  ? UnionOmit<NonNullable<T>, K>
  : UnionOmit<T, K>;
type RecursiveOmitHelper<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = {
  [P in keyof T]: RecursiveOmit<T[P], K>;
};
type RecursiveOmit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = T extends {
  [P in K]: any;
}
  ? NullUnionOmit<RecursiveOmitHelper<T, K>, K>
  : RecursiveOmitHelper<T, K>;

const cleanSolarSystem: RecursiveOmit<SolarSystem, "__typename"> = {
  //__typename: "SolarSystem",
  id: 123,
  name: "The Solar System",
  star: {
    //__typename: "Planet",
    id: 123,
    inhabitants: null,
    name: "Sun",
    size: 9999,
  },
  planets: [
    {
      //__typename: "Planet",
      id: 123,
      name: "Earth",
      size: 12345,
      inhabitants: [
        {
          //__typename: "LifeForm",
          id: 123,
          name: "Human",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

...and the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsA2cqoJ4DOkAtsgN4CwAUMsgPp1h4AOEIcxEAXMgEQbZchErwDc1WsAAmPEAFdiAI2jiaydpx5EooAOaraRHDwAK2EBDAHkzc5YKm7YANoBdVQF9q1UJFiIUMzgLMHIJekYWNg5uPiCQsXDpWQVlKGsNWO09awJgAC9Y+SUVJJAACzhFYDBgsAdkABlgGAgAMXQoYjdkAB91OUxMT28qX2h4JCaW9s7SSjUGJlZMnl5m1o6uxLVkgZL08NXkbJB9ai8qamWUAFUQYHQQAHliGoAeABUAGmQAaWQEAAHpAQFICCcwDozn19mlYQQ8EosAA+ZAAXmQn0BILY4OQchAAGsQOgAO4gcIAfmQrw+P3+KPCsggADdSlQbsgAHKDTD3R4vN5gL6-AHA0H4066WHFeH9RHIzBozHyIY4yUQz7U5ACp50kXcp68oZVTAQL4osVMtQ8PVC+nW1TXKLIABKEAQcigeXZBoAEhBMKwoKL-hq8RDpbLUtAEUjFKiMeRkM4TMhQMgiRA8OgYFjXDwPV6fcA-cKvmnXNbkJcucXvb6IAaw+LcWCo1C9DGDvGlSqsRGO2E1GmMyB-oXkME8CM1DSTfyHvqKw3S+WaoHg9BW1bGcz3Z7G2Xm8KtyHd86qAgnkRkAhzcEBDh8EQIMQi0f16ePs+hG-iF+XgliiTJeAHBZaAAeigkCVhiNY-1fERviSGRkAARgAJgAZlQtRjl4T5yhQP80GEd9eHwwxaigHhINoZAYLg6JNDiJwqPCSR0OwvCuPHSpqlqcAGjVTBqMYwjUEJTi1EMApYgATmUxSJI8CTbGCeweGcfiGMYpjYMieC2N4eJLFkgzuJ4XiJIMwiAFEcDAcpLKsvJChs3CABYAFY7MY0BBJqOoGl0uSrP0qzoKMm5CI2WZtgC6K9ls-josI-0FGCNzovU9LkGrfj8rUIqqA8VQgA)

All of this is required to cover the following cases:

- Unions
- Nullable Types (which seem like unions, but they're "sticky")
- Functions and any other type that doesn't behave well when mapped. (Function lose their Callable signature)

It's largely equivalent to the other answer, but it has a slightly cleaner approach in my opinion.

Comment: this has a bug with a value like: `Record<string, any> | null`