# Typing recursive function removing property from object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that recursively removes a particular property from all objects. If we write it in Javascript, it would be:

```js
function removeRecursive(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(removeRecursive);
  }

  if (typeof value === "object") {
    return Object.keys(value)
      .filter(key => key !== "remove")
      .reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = removeRecursive(value[key]);
        return acc;
      }, {});
  }
  return value;
};
```

For example:

```js
removeRecursive({
  foo: {
    bar: 'foo.bar',
    remove: 'this'
  },
  remove: 'also-this',
  list: [{
    remove: 'this-as-well',
    baz: 'baz'
  }]
})
```

Would result in:

```js
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "foo.bar"
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "baz": "baz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how I can type this? It seems like I *should* have enough information to be able to return a new type that somehow recursively returns the same type with the `remove` property omitted from any object types.

Comment: Found that this was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487137/how-to-recursively-omit-key-from-type

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this with a generic `Drop` instead of just a literal string `"remove"` but we can set a default value for `Drop` as `"remove"`.

```
type Removed<T, Drop = "remove"> = T extends object ? {
    [K in Exclude<keyof T, Drop>]: Removed<T[K], Drop>
} : T;
```

`T` represents the entire value.  At each level of the object, we want to only keep the keys which are not assignable to our `Drop` key generic: `Exclude<keyof T, Drop>`.  To apply this recursively, the new value for that key must itself be filtered: `Removed<T[K], Drop>`.  The `T extends object ? {...} : T;` is not actually necessary, but leads to cleaner inferred types.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ymAO4w)

This checks out with your sample input and output.  Applying the type to your function is a mess though.

Answer (score 0):

When creating this type, I first had to describe in pseudocode what I was trying to achieve, which I think will make the next part easier to understand. `T` is the type to have the key `O` recursively omitted.

```
def RecursiveOmit(T, O):
    if T is an array (of U):
        then T is an array of RecursiveOmit(U, O)
    if T is an object:
        for each key (K) of T, except K=O:
            apply RecursiveOmit(T, O)
    otherwise keep T as-is
```

Translating this into a TypeScript generic type, we get the following:

```js
type RecursiveOmit<T, O extends string> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? RecursiveOmit<U, O>[]
  : T extends Record<string, any>
  ? {
      [K in Exclude<keyof T, O>]: RecursiveOmit<T[K], O>;
    }
  : T;
```

This works well with top-level objects as well as top-level lists of objects, both with deeply nested properties to omit.

Note that the array check (`T extends (infer U)`) must be done before the object check, since TypeScript will consider an array to be an object, which will break your array type!

Here's a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDGBXKBnASwDdgB5AWwJgB4AVAGjlLlBmADsATPOPGKAuwDmAPjgBeOLRYg2XHgApBAM2BQ4AVQCUAbQC6AWABQcOAH50WXIRIUq1DY1Ij9x0wC4pMud0uZonNR8AsKMAIbsiCJu5nAA3jGmpjoA0nCCcACiIJgANticwNQA1sCIEMpSTiJ6nhg4+MRklDS0qXrVANyJcAC+MZ603UbGSChwAGIQEBLxMVDA5BAknsGCQsOmpcBgnuzY5ABGaptwuQR8ngkmSQtLK7z866dbwDt7B8dQL2cXMFc9Ux3ZbAVZPYQ-V7vOD7I4nHq9fQ-CCHABWAJuSTgwIeawhgLg212MM+8MxfVOiL0pxR6Lm5JxoMeIQ2PSJHzh3x650u9KxQMWILBLMhhLexNhXx+VORaIx-Oxgtx4NZ5KhEtJXPJvUpwx1xlGyFQUwgABk-rMTfokQajP52HwEMBefVrE07DQTea+IwAESM31iSQ6GIh8nXBXsuAARnoBJ5-zgOjiYuhsd+vOTqeJ0b6HTgtKu2c8ud6ebjaoLcvixZjjATnizUdL+cLNebfT6FaxvW7cA6xmpxiAA) I made with a test on a matrix of nested objects with properties to remove. You can try switching the array check and object check to see what I mean on array types.