# Generic to recursively modify a given type/interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I am struggling to make a generic which would recursively modify all elements found in a structure of nested, recursive data. Here is an example of my data structure. Any post could have an infinite number of comments with replies using this recursive data definition.

```js
type Post = {
    user: string,
    content: string,
    comments: Comment[],
    reactions: Reaction[],
}

type Comment = {
    user: string,
    content: string,
    replies: Comment[],
}

type Reaction = {
    user: string,
    reaction: "laugh" | "cry" | "smile",
}
```

What I would like is a generic wrapper that I could use with these and *any other data types* that would replace every `user` field with something else. I could do this for the top level:

```js
type UserFilled<T> = Omit<"user", T> & { user: { id: string, name: string }}
```

But this would only change the `user` field for the Post. I would also like it to crawl down and replace the change the `user` field for each of the comments, and if there were more fields, for the reactions, likes, or any other structures with a `user` in them.

I've seen [this answer about omitting something recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54487392/8620945) but I was not able to add the modified property back in using a union and I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way to do this while not just omitting but also replacing the field?

For example, using the generic I would like to be able to do this:

```js
const post: Post = {
    user: "1234",
    content: "this is a post",
    comments: [{
        user: "3456",
        content: "I agree",
        replies: [{
            user: "1234",
            content: "thanks",
        }],
    }],
    reactions: [{
        user: "5678",
        reaction: "smile",
    }],
};

const postWUserInfo: UserFilled<Post> = {
    user: { id: "1234", name: "Bob" },
    content: "this is a post",
    comments: [{
        user: { id: "3456", name: "Jim" },
        content: "I agree",
        replies: [{
            user: { id: "1234", name: "Bob" },
            content: "thanks",
        }],
    }],
    reactions: [{
        user: { id: "5678", name: "Jim" },
        reaction: "smile",
    }],
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a DeepReplace utility that would recursively check and replace keys. Also I'd strongly suggest to only replace value and make sure the key will stay same.

```js
// "not object"
type Primitive = string | Function | number | boolean | Symbol | undefined | null 

// If T has key K ("user"), replace it
type ReplaceKey<T, K extends string, R> = T extends Record<K, unknown> ? Omit<T, K> & Record<K, R> : T

// Check and replace object values
type DeepReplaceHelper<T, K extends string, R, ReplacedT = ReplaceKey<T, K, R>> = {
    [Key in keyof ReplacedT]: ReplacedT[Key] extends Primitive ? ReplacedT[Key] : ReplacedT[Key] extends unknown[] ? DeepReplace<ReplacedT[Key][number], K, R>[] : DeepReplace<ReplacedT[Key], K, R>
}

// T = object, K = key to replace, R = replacement value
type DeepReplace<T, K extends string, R> = T extends Primitive ? T : DeepReplaceHelper<T, K, R>

// Define new type for "user" key
interface UserReplacement {
    id: string
    name: string
}


type UserFilled<T> = DeepReplace<T, "user", UserReplacement>
```

[Typescript Playground with step by step explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgwgewLZIgO2FAvFA3gWACgoSoBXAZwgCcAuKC4agSzQHMAaI0qAYwQzpg9Ri3ZdipahDAAbZhAoB+evGSoMAbQC6EgL5EioSFAAKCRtjzdSlGiKatONkv0EYHY55NfqhFVUQUIR0JHmkAQ15gZgEAqAAlCCiYgVCiA0IjcGgklNi0KwIfcio6BkdxFyhI6IL6ACJZCLI2AAsGqAAfKAbeahBOnoaKJGZZCAb9Q0IAelnetARMBAAjACsIaM7jCGyTUxYxmIA3aBxRJ26oADEyNDqBa7QyJFWaa9WEBAmIwp6AMogN4-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-C0cGKNdeiZGhN0mBjiSNSlLKVMzqglPdKW9BB6J80yYG0Wg8OtO0oGYsd6OZZgjULSDBOiX1AJIMK4XFaypV0oMjUOVCmWYM48Kcm1uKNNKnTY4AIOWFD2E5BAoHBdqcOkSrSGfHKzICkBtF6kgYpqx1CgazVVjITBkq4ybHWoagIhJBrMp4LbSHoAa8uJAq9T09CYwQOMdFGraU0UYzlJokwQuW1aSRcpAmswQcnrWriqFkS6eGfeTFJMiBVT2obtE0F43hoXQyX-C6su2oCoGAhBNWqni6sKCIVrWjMQcWncmQpCh-p2qAgbAHKwZBwb8ubf8MhmOSFOpkHtO1I6iuNJx-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)

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I need, brilliant. It's too bad the implementation has to be so complex (you appear to be a TypeScript master), but the abstraction is spot on.

Comment: Thank you :) I've added comments explaining every step to the playground link, hope it will help you to become "TypeScript master" as well :D

Comment: Really appreciate it. This might be worth publishing as a library on NPM. A lot of people could reach for these advanced "Utility Types", instead of just having `Omit` I think there could be a lot of use for your `DeepOmit, Replace, DeepReplace` etc...