# How to merge properties from union of objects

Tags: typescript

I can get all keys of a union by `type UnionKeys<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: Key }[keyof T]`

```
type MyUnion = {x: 'a', y: 'b'} |  {x: 'aa', z: 'c'}
type T1 = UnionKeys<MyUnion> // 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
```

How do I get the merged type of a union?

```
type MergedUnion<T> = ?????
type T2 = MergedUnion<MyUnion> // `{x: 'a' | 'aa', y: 'b', z: 'c'}`
```

Comment: Even `UnionKeys` doesn't work as you expect. `UnionKeys<MyUnion>` is just `'x'` (same as you'd use regular `keyof MyUnion`)

Comment: Where did you get that definition of `UnionKeys` ? It does not appear to work

Comment: `type UnionKeys<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: Key }[keyof T]` is my homebrew. It result in `'x' | 'y' | 'z'`on both 3.4.3 and 3.5-dev, but I like your version better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done. We map over `UnionKeys` ( I used a different definition, using distributive conditional types) and we use another distributive conditional type to extract a union of all values that a specific key can have:

```
type MyUnion = {x: 'a', y: 'b'} |  {x: 'aa', z: 'c'}
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type UnionValues<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends Record<K, infer U> ? U: never;
type MergedUnion<T> = { [P in UnionKeys<T>]: UnionValues<T, P> }
```

Comment: Nice! Could you explain why `T extends unknown ? keyof T : never` behaves differently than regular `keyof T`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Because of distributive conditional types, you can read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter/51651684#51651684. I'm sorry I've written up the explanation for distribution so many times my fingers rebel at the very thought of writing it again :)).