# Convert optional properties of a TypeScript interface to nullable properties

Tags: typescript, null, undefined, conditional-types, mapped-types

I have the following type:

```
interface A {
  p1: string
  p2?: string
}
```

I would like to generate a sub-type `B` with optional properties converted to nullable properties. Something equivalent to:

```
interface B {
  p1: string
  p2: string | null
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
type VuexPick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]-?: T[P] extends undefined ? null : T[P];
};

type B = VuexPick<A, "p1" | "p2">;
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type `B` gets resolved to this:

```
type B = {
  p1: string extends undefined ? null : string
  p2: string | undefined extends undefined ? null : string | undefined
};
```

`string | undefined` as supertype does not extend `undefined`, it is the other way around. So you end up with this type:

```
type B = {
    p1: string;
    p2: string;
}
```

You could instead create a `UndefinedToNull` type, which causes a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to be applied, as `T` is a [naked type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter) now.

```
type VuexPick2<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]-?: UndefinedToNull<T[P]>;
};

type UndefinedToNull<T> = T extends undefined ? null : T

type B2 = VuexPick2<A, "p1" | "p2">; // type B2 = { p1: string; p2: string | null;}
```

E.g. type `UndefinedToNull<string | undefined>` is the same as `B4`:

```
type B4 = 
| (string extends undefined ? null: string) 
| (undefined extends undefined ? null: undefined) // type B4 = string | null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=7&pln=26&pc=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUwEYBcUDOwATgJYB2A5mhgEwD8uBJFKAviimcBIQGYCGAY2gAhAOp9SXACbIqWBkTKV0YagqbkoAHyikArgBsDrdqEhQAanogAPAArEBAawA8AFQA0UANJRbXUik8KCcIEAB7Hig3AD4EWXQAbTsoMh8AXQBaemjk9L8bAKCoPUCIHjIIGVpdQwMoXDc8gG5WVpQzEXirWwdnFxgvACIsIe0oEeohmPbOy2t7Rydqdy9ffwhA4NCIqNj41CSUtO8snIBVMorSKrdwgDk69zyZttNwaEupcsqpO8ejO44og3AUisFSt9rlUoDV9EYGtF3uZhNRugs+ssBsNRuNJtNZh8oMIAMzxL4-G5-B5PRhKcaQylVGIdInCAAs8QAFHSKGDNsVGdDqrUjOolABKcZcoW-flbEpXOVwuq4WVUiUoIA)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
export type OptionalTuNullable<O> = {
  [K in keyof O]-?: undefined extends O[K] ? NonNullable<O[K]> | null : O[K];
};
```

So for instance:

```
type R = {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string | null;
  d: string | undefined;
};

type A = OptionalTuNullable<R>;
// A: {
//     a: string;
//     b: string | null;
//     c: string | null;
//     d: string | null;
// }
```

Then, for the "Pick" part, you can just resort to the standard `Pick` type:

```
type B = Pick<A, "a" | "c">;
// B: {
//   a: string;
//   c: string | null;
// }
```

Summing up, I think this would work for your use case:

```
type VuexPick<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<OptionalTuNullable<T>, K>

type C = VuexPick<R, 'c'>
// C: {
//   c: string | null;
// }
```