# In Typescript, how to understand 'extends' of union types?

Tags: typescript, extends, union-types

Here is my try:

```
type Comb1 = "123" | "1234";
type Comb2 = "123" | "1234" | "12345";

type Res<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;

// Res1 === "123" | "1234"
type Res1 = isExtends<Comb1, Comb2>;

// Res2 === "123" | "1234"
type Res2 = isExtends<Comb2, Comb1>;
```

Why Res2 is not 'never'?

And what 'extends' do in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: what is a "naked type parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter)

Comment: Check this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and i've got the key point is to understand distributive conditional types. @ford04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your `isExtends` type to:

```
type isExtends<T, U> = T extends U ? 1 : 0;
```

then You'll see:

```
type Res1 = isExtends<"123" | "1234", "123" | "1234" | "12345">; // Res1 === 1
type Res2 = isExtends<"123" | "1234" | "12345", "123" | "1234">; // Res2 === 0 | 1
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

So, now return to your original case

```
type isExtends<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
type Res2 = isExtends<"123" | "1234" | "12345", "123" | "1234">;
```

it results in `"123" | "1234"` because it's de facto `("123" | "1234") | never`

This

```
isExtends<"123" | "1234" | "12345", "123" | "1234">
```

can be expanded as:

```
isExtends<"123" | "1234", "123" | "1234"> | isExtends("12345", "123" | "1234")
```

which is

```
("123" | "1234") | never
```

which is simply

```
"123" | "1234"
```